# Django Uncaught ReferenceError: flat_plate is not defined

Tags: javascript, django

First of I introducte the system.id into my JavaScrip which is an unique integer, and this gives no problems. 
However when I try to 'introduce' the system.system_type variable (which is a Django CharField) into my JavaScript I get the error: Django Uncaught ReferenceError: flat_plate is not defined.

The (simplified) System model is defined as follows:

```
class System(models.Model):
    system_name = models.CharField(default='default_name', max_length=200)
    system_type = models.CharField(default='flat_plate', max_length=50, choices = SYSTEM_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

Here SYSTEM_TYPE_CHOICES is defined as:

```
SYSTEM_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('flat_plate', 'flat_plate'),
    ('helical_coil', 'helical_coil')
)
```

The simplified Django template with JavaScript which I try to run is defined as follows:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

<script>
{% block jquery %}

{% autoescape off %}
    system_id = {{ system.id }} // runs without a problem
    system_type =  {{ system.system_type }} // Gives an error
{% endautoescape %}

    console.log("system_id is: "+system_id)
    console.log("system_type is: "+system_type)

{% endblock %}
</script>

{% block content %}
<p>{{system.system_type}} gives either "flat_plate" or "helical_coil"</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Did you define `SYSTEM_TYPE_CHOICES` before writing the class code?

Comment: The SYSTEM_TYPE_CHOICES is defined in choices.py. I can easily reference the actual value using template tags, i.e.: {{ system.system_type }} however for some reason I can not read this field in my JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JavaScript you need quotation marks since it's a string:

```
system_type =  '{{ system.system_type }}';
```